# 3-dim simple complex Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

If we know that a 3-dimensional Lie algebra $L$ with $[L,L]=L$ is simple.

How to prove that the only (up to isomorphism) 3-dimensional complex Lie algebra $L$ with $L=[L,L]$ is $sl_2(\mathbb C)$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ be a basis of $L$. Since $[L,L]=L$, 
$$
(f_1,f_2,f_3):=([e_2,e_3],[e_3,e_1],[e_1,e_2])
$$ 
is again a basis of $L$. Hence we may write the $f_i$ as linear combinations of the $e_i$, i.e., $f_i=\sum a_{ij}e_j$, with invertible coefficient matrix $A=(a_{ij})$. One checks that $A$ must be symmetric, and that every invertible symmetric matrix $A$ determines a Lie algebra $L_A$. Then two such Lie algebras $L_A$ and $L_B$ are isomorphic if and only if there is a matrix $M\in GL_3(\mathbb{C})$ such that
$$
B=\det(M)(M^{-1})^tAM^{-1}.
$$
In other words, $L_a$ and $L_B$ are isomorphic if and only if $A$ and $B$ lie in the same $G$-orbit under the action of $G:=\mathbb{C}^*\times GL_3(\mathbb{C})$ given by $(t,C)A=tCAC^T$ on the space of symmetric $3\times 3$ matrices. By linear algebra (Principal axis theorem), the system of representatives is just the identity. Hence there is only one simple complex Lie algebra of dimension $3$ (we only need that $L$ is perfect, because in dimension $3$ this means simplicity).

Comment: Thank you for your continuous help

Comment: The group is just GL3, no? (Also, in the last sentence: you only used perfection, not simplicity)

Comment: Also: you can always write the fi in terms of the ei, because the latter are a basis! What you mean is that the matrix A is invertible (and that is why there is only one orbit) and that is equivalent to perfection.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to check that the matrix $A$ must be symmetric.

Comment: @Ronald, write down what the Jacobi identity  means for $e_1$, $e_2$ and $e_3$.

Comment: Thanks Mariano, I actually have more questions and I need some details on: what are the algebras $L_A$ and $L_B$? How can one understands the fact that $L_A$ and $L_B$ are isomorphic iff there is a matrix $M$ ... ? Why $B$ is written in this way? What is $(t,C)$? I am sorry but I'm still new to this theory

Comment: @Ronald: you can check all the details in jacobson's book on Lie algebras, page $13$ and $14$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Yes, thank you for the corrections.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the adjoint representation. Since the algebra is perfect, we have $tr\  ad(x)=0$ for all $x \in L$. Since $ad(x)$ has determinant zero, because $[x,x]=0$, we see that the characteristic polynomial of $ad(x)$ is of the form $f(t) = t^3 + c(x) t$ for some scalar $c(x)$ depending on $x$.

If we had $c(x) = 0$ for all $x$, then $ad(x)$ would be nilpotent for all $x$, By Engel's theorem, then, L is a nilpotent Lie algebra and, in particular, not perfect. This is absurd.

It follows that there exists a nonzero h in L such that $c(x)$ is not zero. This implies that $ad(x)$ is diagonalizable with three distinct eigenvalues. One of them is zero, and $h$ is an eigenvector for zero. Let x and y be eigenvector for the other two eigenvalues. Since $tr \ ad(x)$ is zero, these two eigenvalues are $a$ and $-a$ for some complex number $a$.

Compute now that $[x,y]$ is an eigenvector for $ad(h)$ of eigenvalue zero, so it is a scalar multiple if $h$, say $b, h$. If $b$ is zero, then clearly $[L,L]$ is spanned by $x$ and $y$, which is against our hypothesis. Therefore $b$ is not zero.

The Lie algebra is therefore completely determined by two nonzero scalars with brackets given by $[h,x]=ax, [h,y]=-at, [x,y]=bh$

Now play a bit with rescaling the three elements $x$, $y$ and $h$ to get an isomorphism with $sl_2$: consider the basis $\{\frac{2h}{a}, \frac{2x}{ab}, y\}$.

Comment: This is very nice solution. Do you know a reference which uses a slimier approach?