# If x is in the derived algebra, show that Tr(ad a)=0

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra, and let $a\in [L,L]$. How to prove that $trace(ad_a)=0$?

Comment: This is a recent duplicate. Give me a second.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan:  Were you perhaps thinking of your answer to [this Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632814/computation-of-killing-form)?

Comment: @hardmath: no, someone asked this exact question recently. It might've been deleted though.

Comment: $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(BA)$, and the fact that $ad:L\to\mathfrak{gl}_n$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I also remember that we have answered the same question recently, and I think, also posted by the same user (who might have deleted the question along with both answers).

Comment: I don't remember that I asked this question before.. And I didn't delete any question. It is not possible actually to delete a question with answers

Comment: Ronald: sorry, I might be mistaken. But the question definitely was there a few days ago, with tag "Lie algebras". Can you find it ?

Comment: No problem. But you may mean this question .. Which is asked by me and still active http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1625573/3-dim-simple-complex-lie-algebra

Comment: No, I mean the very same question. My answer was: $ad(L)=ad([L,L])=[ad(L),ad(L)]$. It might have been a user who was removed upon request.

Comment: I think your answer is nice, why you don't add it here . interested people can see different answers

Comment: Ronald, thanks for the compliment! I cannot add an answer, because the question is on hold.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $x=[a,b]$, Jacobi implies that $ad_x=ad_a(ad_b)-ad_b(ad_a)$. Since $trace(fg)=trace(gf)$ the result follows.